# Why is Cygwin64's MinGW compiler producing 32-bit pointers rather than 64-bit pointers?

Tags: windows, pointers, cygwin, mingw, sizeof

Doing 'sizeof(char *)' from in 'C' programs shows pointers to be 4 bytes long rather than 8 bytes long in 64-bit Windows using Cygwin64's MinGW compiler.  I'm specifically using the compiler 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe', which is the only MinGW compiler that I've found so far in Cygwin64.  I've read about the 'WOW64' system in Windows that emulates a 32-bit environment but doubt that this is connected to the issue.  Everything I've read so far states that pointers from 64-bit MinGW compilers should be 8 bytes long.  So I'm confused about this and of course wondering how I might therefore be able to compile programs that use 64-bit pointers with Cygwin64's MinGW.

Comment: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc is a 32bit compiler. `i686` = 32bit platform

Comment: Thank you and that makes sense then.  But doesn't Cygwin64 also have a 64-bit MinGW compiler tucked away somewhere inside of it?  You'd think so being that it's designed for 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default cross compiler, but instead there 
are 2 sets for 64 and 32 bit.

mingw64-x86_64-*
mingw64-i686-*

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-01/msg00035.html

Comment: The webpage you reference contains interesting information, yet I can't make sense of it so far.  I don't understand what he's referencing.  Specifically, the '--host' items mentioned confuse me.  I don't know where these apply.  When I try them with either the compiler above or simply the 'gcc.exe' compiler I get "unrecogized command line option."  Can anyone clarify what this is about?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to simply use a different MinGW compiler that I've downloaded.  After I'd isolated the specific Cygwin64 download-file that provides the MinGW compiler and then unpacked and searched it for its executables, I found that it only contains the one compiler mentioned above that is a 32-bit MinGW compiler.  So being that I can't yet make helpful sense out of the reference kindly provided below this by matzeri to that webpage information, I'm considering the following as my best solution so far to this problem.  I've found a NON-Cygwin 64-bit MinGW compiler that's available online and have installed it to use in addition to Cygwin's various compilers whenever I need to create true 64-bit executables.  I downloaded it from the website 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/', and it seems to work great with it producing 64-bit pointers!  (WARNING:  A more heavily-referenced 64-bit MinGW compiler named "Dev-Cpp 5.11 TDM-GCC 4.9.2 Orwell+Mingw" that I looked into before this one shows as containing a Trojan-Horse virus when scanned with the antivirus App ClamWin!)